# t.then() is not a function; however, deferred object.promise is being returned

Tags: angularjs

I realize there are a million of these questions on stack overflow and I've looked at several. It always seems to be a situation where someone is not returning back a promise. That is not the case this time... I am most definitely returning back a promise in my `LoginFactory`. The error occurs from my controller when I do a login post. I can only assume this is some strange bundling and minification error with my scripts; however, I am new to angular.

**Why is angular complaining about not returning a deferred object?**

```
var LoginFactory = function ($http, $q) {
console.log("calling login factory constructor");
return function (emailAddress, password, rememberMe) {
    var deferredObject = $q.defer();

    $http.post('/Account/Login', {
        Email: emailAddress,
        Password: password,
        RememberMe: rememberMe
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log("in success", data);
        if (data === "True") {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: true });
        } else {
            deferredObject.resolve({ success: true });
        }
    }).error(function () {
        console.log("in error");
        deferredObject.resolve({ success: false });
    });
    console.log("returning deferred object", deferredObject);
    return deferredObject.promise;
}
}

LoginFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];  


var LoginController = function ($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.loginForm = {
    emailAddress: '',
    password: '',
    rememberMe: false,
    returnUrl: $routeParams.returnUrl
};

$scope.login = function () {
    var result = LoginFactory($scope.loginForm.emailAddress, $scope.loginForm.password, $scope.loginForm.rememberMe);
    console.log("result in login func",result);
    result.then(function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            if ($scope.loginForm.returnUrl !== undefined) {
                $location.path('/routeOne');
            } else {
                $location.path($scope.loginForm.returnUrl);
            }
        } else {
            $scope.loginForm.loginFailure = true;
        }
    });
}
}

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'LoginFactory'];
```

[image]

**Adding minified script. The return promise looks weird. I'm not familiar enough with js to know if that's correct**

```
LoginFactory = function(n, t) {
return console.log("calling login factory constructor"),
    function(i, r, u) {
        var f = t.defer();
        return n.post("/Account/Login", {
            Email: i,
            Password: r,
            RememberMe: u
        }).success(function(n) {
            console.log("in success", n);
            n === "True" ? f.resolve({
                success: !0
            }) : f.resolve({
                success: !0
            })
        }).error(function() {
            console.log("in error");
            f.resolve({
                success: !1
            })
        }), console.log("returning deferred object", f), f.promise
    }
};
LoginFactory.$inject = ["$http", "$q"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the underside of so-called John Papa style and `$inject` annotations.

`LoginFactory` variable results in having the same name in multiple scopes (as in 'function scope', not 'Angular scope'); something that will never happen with anonymous functions and array annotations.

Function annotation and function signature are mismatched:

```
var LoginController = function ($scope, $routeParams) { ... }

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'LoginFactory'];
```

This results in getting `LoginFactory` from parent scope, where it is a factory function, not an instance. Thus the result of `LoginFactory(...)` call is a function, not a promise (this is what `console.log` outputs).

It should be

```
var LoginController = function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, LoginFactory) { ... }
```

Two things can be done to never let this happen again.

The one is to use named functions instead of variables, so `$inject` annotations could be hoisted. This allows to have annotation and function signature side by side:

```
LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'LoginFactory'];  

function LoginController ($scope, $routeParams, $location, LoginFactory) { ... }
```

Another one is TDD. Write unit tests at the same time when you write the app. This allows to spot rookie mistakes on sight and deduce the complex ones by eliminating potential causes. If `LoginFactory` were already tested at the time when `LoginController` was written, there would be no doubt that DI just went wrong.

Also, the code above uses deprecated `success` method and [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You must return the deferredObject (not deferredObject.promise) 
And in result do `result.promise.then`

The then function will be execute when promise is loaded

Comment: That seems like pretty much the same thing. I just tried it though and still getting the exact same error. It's basically saying `promise` is not defined.

changes: `return deferredObject;` & `result.promise.then(function (result) {`